# How to print only parts of text file in bundle

Tags: ios, swift, text-files

How to do print only select lines from your text file, based on what button is clicked.

So if button one is clicked, line 4 of text from my text file will print to the UILabel.

Right now it prints the entire file.

```
@IBOutlet weak var AboutLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func GetAboutInfo(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Meditations", ofType: "txt") {
        if let text = try? String(contentsOfFile: path,
                                  encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            AboutLabel.text = text
        }
    }
}
```

Would like it to only print the line of text I submit based on what button is clicked on a previous screen.

Comment: Once you've load the file, you'd have to parse based on your needs

Comment: A text file is a poor choice. Put the lines of text into a plist (either array or dictionary depending on your needs) or if the file is large enough, put the data in a database so you don't need to load the whole into memory just to get one line of text.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the text as per your requirement, here i'm assuming the lines are separated via a line break *\n*

Plus it would be better to load your string once outside the method

And as suggested by @rmaddy a better option would be a `.plist`

```
let meditationsPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Meditations", ofType: "txt")!
let meditationText = try String(contentsOfFile: meditationsPath,
            encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
let meditationTextArray = meditationText.split(separator: "\n")
```

Your `getAboutInfo` would become

```
// Name your methods and variables with camel case
@IBAction func getAboutInfo(_ sender: UIButton) {

     // Assign the button tag for index
     let index = sender.tag

     if index < meditationTextArray.count {
       let text = meditationTextArray[index]              
       self.aboutLabel.text = text
     }
}
```